# Check to see if at least one input field out of many has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 input fields and I want to check to see if at least 1 has a value. If none have values I want to return.

Here is what I have and I know if doesn't work because it doesn't enter the if statement if nothing has been entered.

```js
if ($('#Name').val() != "" && $('#State').val() != "" && $('#City').val() != "" && $('#Zip').val() != "") {
  showAlert("You need to select at least one of the following: Name, State, City, or Zip", 'error');
  return;
}
```

if none have a value I want to show a message and return without further processing.

Comment: So what part of your code isn't working? Your `!=` should probably be `==`? Your basically doing `does it have a value && does it have a value && does it have a value && does it have a value`

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct logic?

Comment: If **any** has value: `$('#Name').val() || $('#State').val() ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So instead of checking that the value is not empty you should check that they ARE empty:

```
if (!$('#Name').val() && !$('#State').val() && !$('#City').val() && !$('#Zip').val()) {
  return alert("You need to select at least one of the following: Name, State, City, or Zip", 'error');
}
```

You can also put the `alert` after the `return` to make it shorter.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/swenx6t3/)

Comment: The second example don't work. A console.log($('#Name, #State, #City, #Zip').val())  only prints the first element value.

Comment: Good catch. I've removed that example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the `inputs` type `text` and filter them checking for the value being present:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Check").on("click", function () {
    // Will return the inputs containing value.
    var anyValue = $("input[type=text]").filter(function () {
        return $(this).val().trim() !== "";
    });

    // If there's at least one containing any value.
    console.log(anyValue.length !== 0);
  });
});
```

I considered the markup below:

```
<input name="Name" id="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="City" id="City" type="text" placeholder="City" />
<input name="State" id="State" type="text" placeholder="State" />
<input name="Zip" id="Zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip" />
<button id="Check">Check</button>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/h2stzog4/)